# Is it possible to call a function of a subclass from parent class?

Tags: python

```
class A(object):
    def xx():
        # do something

    def yy():
        # do something

class B(A):
    def func():
        # do something

# How to make it possible?
a = A()
a.func()
```

Now I want to add func() to class A, however I CANNOT change class A, so I created a subclass of A and add func() to the subclass. How can I call func() from A instance?

I tried to initiate with class B, however, there are many instances, so I need to change many many locations. Is there a better way to do it? Ideally with class A.

```
# This works, however, I need to change A() to B() everywhere.
# Are there easy ways to do it without changing A() to B()?
a = B()
a.func()
```

Comment: Why CANNOT change A?

Comment: There are many ways to change a class in Python. If you explain what you are trying to achieve and why you think you cannot change the class, you may get other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setattr()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#setattr)):

```
class A:
    def xx(self):
        print('xx')

    def yy(self):
        print('yy')

class B(A):
    def func(self):
        print('func')

setattr(A, 'func', B.func) # or setattr(A, B.func.__name__, B.func)

a = A()
a.func()
```

Prints:

```
func
```

Comment: Or simply `A.func = B.func`?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do such thing because class B inherits from Class A not the reverse, so you can use B.xx() but you can't use A.func().

For more information about inheritance in Python, look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python/)

As Andrej said, you can use `setattr()` method to define new attribute for class A.
Look [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/setattr) for more information about `setattr()` method.